# terminal Character Encoding in java

Tags: java, terminal, character-encoding

I want to encode terminal character in java.

I used this codes to encode the characters.

```
        byte[] ptext = str1.getBytes(ISO_8859_9);

        String value = new String(ptext, UTF_8);
```

[terminal pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beTwo.png)

But , the output comes like this

[output pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzEHR.jpg)

How can I solve this ?

Comment: What happens if you simply print `str1` without any character set conversion?

Comment: If I run my code without character set conversion the output comes with more unwanted characters.